# AS3 - How do you Ignore a class (Error #1009)?

Tags: class, actionscript-3

I have created a class for a MovieClip creating coins for the player (char) to pick up. All the class is suppose to do is add to the score and coinscollected variables, and then remove the one coin from the stage. But when I change the frame using `gotoAndStop(#);`, the console spams

> ErrorType: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference."

Coin class:

```
public class coin extends MovieClip{
    var char:MovieClip;
    var MainTimeLine = MovieClip(root);
    public function coin() {
        // constructor code
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);

    }

    function update(event:Event):void{
        if(MainTimeLine.currentFrame!=5){
            char=MovieClip(root).char;
            if(this.hitTestObject(char)){
                this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
                parent.removeChild(this);
                MainTimeLine.score++;
                MainTimeLine.coinscollected++;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Just a tip for code readability best practice.  Use Uppercase first letter for CLASSES, and lower case first letter for instances/variable names.   So in your case, `coin` should be `Coin` and `MainTimeLine` should be `mainTimeLine`.  It also helps with the code highlighting on stackoverflow

Comment: You can either fix this error or ignore it with a try/catch statement (*really* bad practice). Also, the player might get confused if you capitalize variable names.

Comment: Is the coin animated? In this case, you should also execute the function `stop()` before it is removed. Also, what line is this error on? Also, you should change `var char:MovieClip` to just `var char` so it's not null. (Keep in mind all functions and variables should be camel cased.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root isn't populated until your display object has been added to the display list.  You need to listen for that event before setting the variable.

```
var char:MovieClip;
var MainTimeLine; //do not initialize here, root is null at this point

public function coin() {
    // constructor code

    //root is still null here sometimes too, so see if it's populated yet
    if(root){
        init(); //root is populated, skip to initialization
    }else{
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,addedToStage);  //root isn't populated yet, listen for added to stage and then initialize
    }
}

private function addedToStage(e:Event = null):void {
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,addedToStage);
    init();
}

private function init():void {
    MainTimeLine = MovieClip(root)
    this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
}
```

---

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but I just realized that I should have elaborated more on the error. The 1009 error is directing towards "coin/update()".

Comment: Answer still stands.  That's where it will error because that's where your trying to use your `MainTimeLine` var - which was set to `null`.